# I am searching for a function to go throw every pixel in a pygame.Rect

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, pygame

I have a problem. I want to animate an area, which is saved in a pygame rectangle (`pygame.Rect`).

Is there a function like:

```py
for pixel in pygame.Rect:
```

Comment: What do you want to do with those pixels? pygame.draw.rect() can draw a rectangle based on a pygame.Rect

Comment: pygame rect its just an object there is no pixel .... have you try pygame.PixelArray

Comment: When you say 'draw every pixel' do you want them all to be the same colour?  Because there are ways of doing that without iterating over each pixel individually.

Comment: No I want to have every pixel a different colour

Comment: Create a `Surface` with the size of the rect, then change the pixels color, then `blit()` the `Surface` to the `Rect` position.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested loop to iterate through all pixels in a rectangle:

```py
rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
```

```py
for x in range(rect.left, rect.right):
    for y in range(rect.top, rect.bottom):
```